# Is there anything wrong with following selectQuery ?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
int getIdForSong(Song song){

    String selectQuery = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + SONG_TITLE + "=" + song.getSongTitle() + " AND " + ARTIST_NAME + "=" + song.getArtistName();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
    return id;
}
```

I am getting and exception near "=". Anyone?

Comment: You've to give your `"="` instead of `"='"` Have a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_rawquery)

Comment: Also int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)); throws CursorOutOfBoundIndex.. I dont know why because id should be returned at getString(0) as the id field is a primary key autoincrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change selectQuery Value as :

```
"SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + SONG_TITLE + " = '" + song.getSongTitle() + "' AND  '" + ARTIST_NAME + "' = '" + song.getArtistName() + "'";
```

Comment: wherever "' you find, add double quotes and single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int getIdForSong(Song song){

String selectQuery = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + SONG_TITLE + "= ' " + song.getSongTitle() + "' AND " + ARTIST_NAME + "= ' " + song.getArtistName()+" ' ";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
return id;
}
```

Comment: int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)); is also throwing CursorOutOfBoundindex... I dont know why because getString(0) should return the first field id which I have kept primary and autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

For CursorOutOfBoundException,

After Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); ,

if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()){

```
  int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
  return id;
```

}

Comment: Thanx a lot but can you tell me why does this exactly happens??